# Powershell - Looking for a better way to check if multple processes have completed

Tags: powershell, start-process

I've got a script that creates some processes using the Start-Process command.  There could be hundreds of processes running. The script works just fine, but I'm hoping someone can provide me with a more elegant way to check if the processes I started have all completed?  One that doesn't require any input as I'm looking to create an automated solution.

Below is a code sample.

```
$procList = @()

$cmd = "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\PING.EXE"
$cmdArgs = " nos3nse.com"
$proc1 = Start-Process $cmd -ArgumentList $cmdArgs -PassThru
$proc2 = Start-Process $cmd -ArgumentList $cmdArgs -PassThru
$proc3 = Start-Process $cmd -ArgumentList $cmdArgs -PassThru

$procObject = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    id = $proc1.Id
    name = $proc1.Name
    startTime = $proc1.StartTime
    dtlLogFile = $dtlLogFileTemp
}
$procList += $procObject

$procObject = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    id = $proc2.Id
    name = $proc2.Name
    startTime = $proc2.StartTime
    dtlLogFile = $dtlLogFileTemp
}
$procList += $procObject

$procObject = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    id = $proc3.Id
    name = $proc3.Name
    startTime = $proc3.StartTime
    dtlLogFile = $dtlLogFileTemp
}
$procList += $procObject

# Is there a better way to find out if these jobs have all completed?
$ppFlag = $true
while ($ppFlag) {
  foreach ($proc in $procList) {
    $chkJob = Get-Process -id $proc.id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($chkJob.HasExited -eq $false) 
      { 
        Write-Host ("looping")
        Write-Host ("Sleeping 2 seconds") -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
        break #break foreach loop
      }
  } #foreach
  if ($chkJob.HasExited -ne $false) { $ppFlag = $false }
} #while
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
$a = start -NoNewWindow powershell {timeout 10; 'a done'} -PassThru
$b = start -NoNewWindow powershell {timeout 10; 'b done'} -PassThru
$c = start -NoNewWindow powershell {timeout 10; 'c done'} -PassThru
$a,$b,$c | wait-process

Waiting for  0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
Waiting for  0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
Waiting for  0 seconds, press a key to continue ...

a done
b done
c done
```

Wait-process can be used with an array.  Maybe you should update your question.

```
1..3 | foreach { start -NoNewWindow powershell {timeout 5; 'done'} -PassThru } | 
  wait-process
```

Comment: Yes, that'll work, but I'm looking for a non-interactive solution to help me automate some processing.  I put 3 processes in my example, but I could actually have hundreds.  :-)